# simulating multiple user requests on webserer with python multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-requests, python-multiprocessing

i am trying to simulatie multiple user requests in parallel on a flask server to measure its responsetimes.
i thought multiprocessing would be the right module for it. Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import requests
import datetime
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

HOST = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
API_PATH = '/'
ENDPOINT = [HOST + API_PATH]
MAX_Processes = 10

def send_api_request(ENDPOINT):
    r = requests.get(ENDPOINT)
    print(mp.current_process())
    statuscode = r.status_code
    elapsedtime = r.elapsed
    return statuscode, elapsedtime

def main():
    with Pool() as pool: 
        try:
            #define poolsize
            pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
            print(pool)
            results= pool.map(send_api_request, ENDPOINT)
            print(results)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pool.terminate()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

when i run this code in cli i only get one result printed and i dont know if the 8 processes are being processed.
here is the output:

```
<multiprocessing.pool.Pool state=RUN pool_size=8>
<SpawnProcess name='SpawnPoolWorker-10' parent=19536 started daemon>
200 0:00:00.013491
```

the target is to run 100 or more requests in parallel on the flask server to get the responsetime of every single requests and put them in an csv sheet.

anyone knows how i can get every result from the processes?

Thank you!

Comment: You're calling `pool.map(send_api_request, ENDPOINT)`, but `ENDPOINT` only has a single item, so you're only ever making a single request.

Comment: You probably don't want `pool.map`. Take a look at [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html), and then create a loop that calls `submit` to create each "client".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only get one result because your `ENDPOINT` list  object's length is 1, so you need to set it like `ENDPOINT = [HOST + API_PATH]*8` (8 is number of request)

And also `multithreading` is more suitable in your case because you are only send a `GET` request that is `I/O` bound.

Here is the example by using threadpool approach ;

```
import requests
import datetime
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

HOST = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
API_PATH = '/'
ENDPOINT = [HOST+API_PATH]*8

def send_api_request(ENDPOINT):
    r = requests.get(ENDPOINT)
    statuscode = r.status_code
    elapsedtime = r.elapsed
    return statuscode, elapsedtime

def main():

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as pool: 
        iterator = pool.map(send_api_request, ENDPOINT)

    for result in iterator:
        print(result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**EDIT :**

As an answer to OP's question in the comment:

`POST` request is also `I/O` bound operation. Yes `python` threads are not offer parallelism, works sequentially, but it offers concurency. You can work with another task when your main thread is blocked some `I/O` operation like `time.sleep`, `GET/POST` request, `writing/reading` to a file)

`GIL` is bad when you want to do CPU bound operation, but `GIL` is not bad when you want to do `I/O` bound operation because `GIL` is released by the `Cpython` interpreter when you do a `I/O` bound operation.

Let's say you want to send 4 request to a web server, how this will be work in python, let's examine first 2 steps ;

First thread will create a `socket` object and this thread will ask the kernel using `socket` `syscall`, "hey kernel connect to `127.0.0.1` address on `5000` port and send this `GET` request and also give me the response of this `GET` request". Python will also release the GIL before the socket system call. (This is important)

Kernel will accept your request and  will handle this operation, and also kernel will block you (if you not to tell kernel to not block your `thread/process`) after blocking, kernel will do context switch to let another thread or process run, let's say switched to second thread.

Second thread will try to run. And first, it will check the status of Global Interpreter Lock, it will see that GIL is released. It is well, second thread can run now, this second thread do same thing with first one. It will release the GIL and it will ask to kernel, "hey kernel connect to `127.0.0.1` address on `5000` port and send this `GET` request and also give me the response of this `GET` request"

Yes these steps are sequential, but very fast, you will send your `GET/POST` request quickly.

You will not wait for the result of first request to send second request when you use thread because it offer concurrency

You can also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20418825/10556711)

Please correct me if I'm wrong somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for your input! what i am trying to test is how the web-server reacts to 100 or more requests at once. when i am using multithreading the requests wont be sent in a concurrent manner right? in my understanding multithreading is sending requests in a sequential way and multiprocessing in parallel and thats what i need.

Comment: and i have some more flask routes where i am sending POST requests that i want to test in multiprocessing.

Comment: yes, to add ... the GIL will hold and release the lock so quickly, it pretty much may even seem parallel. I assume you are doing some kind of performance testing with API automation. Threading is the way to go. MultiProcessing is not used for this usecase.

Comment: yes i am doing a performance test on some web-frameworks and testing flask right now. thanks for your answers! helped really much and i will switch to multithreading instead.

Answer (score 0):

So for this particular usecase, you want to use threading and not multiprocessing.
General Rule of thumb is,

MultiProcessing is for when you have CPU intensive tasks, like number crunching.

Threading is for when you have I/O intensive tasks. Like this one you have now, performing API requests, reading and writing to files etc.

I have drafted a simple solution.
It will return 3 lists .

> response_bodies - this is the response of the API, response_results -
> this is the API status_code, api_execution_times - duration of each API

```
import requests
import threading
import datetime
import time
api_execution_count= 100
url= "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python"  # Assuming its one API that you are pulling data from if not you will have to hold them in a list  
request_type= "GET"
api_execution_times= []
response_bodies= []
response_results= []


# you can add variable to pass headers if that applies.


def perform_api_call():
    start_time = time.time()
    recieved_response= requests.request(request_type, url)  # to disable SSL verifications add verify=False

    response_as_text= recieved_response.text 
    response_result= recieved_response.status_code
    api_run_duration= time.time() - start_time  # this will be the time to perform the API call and to get the response and status_code
    api_execution_times.append(api_run_duration)
    response_bodies.append(response_as_text)
    response_results.append(response_result)
    return api_execution_times,response_bodies,response_results


threads= []

for api_counter in range(0,api_execution_count):
    t= threading.Thread(target=perform_api_call)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

    
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()  # this will basically make the code wait for all threads to complete. (All API calls to be made)
    
print(api_execution_times, response_bodies,response_results) # you can then write this to a .csv file
```

Comment: thank you i can work with that but please see my response to above post from @Veysel